# My header's logo is stretching its width in Safari

Tags: css

My website works perfectly in computers and Android smartphones, but when I open my website in an apple smartphone in my home page, my logo gets stretched horizontally occupying almost all my header's width leaving no space for my burger menu (.toggle in my code).

I've searched about it and discovered that when using flexbox in safari we can have some display problems, because it uses old prefixes, so I tried to implement them but nothing changed.

```css
.header {
  background-color: rgb(235, 223, 201);
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 5rem;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom-style: double;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1210px) {
  .logo {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: calc(100% - 50px)
  }
  .menu-one {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%
  }
  .toggle {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    transform: translate(-10px);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .toggle span {
    position: relative;
    width: 36px;
    height: 4px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu-one">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="">
      <div class="lettering">
        <h6><span class="bolder">F</span>ÁTIMA<span class="bolder">C</span>RISTÓVÃO <span class="smaller">by KELLER WILLIAMS</span></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu-two" class="hide">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item" id="proj">
      <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="options">
      <a href="./Atower.html">A-Tower</a>
    </li>
    <li class="options">
      <a href="./muda.html">Muda</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#About-Me">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're not prefixing all your values so it should look like this:

```
.header {
    background-color: rgb(235, 223, 201);
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 5rem;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom-style: double;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1210px) {

.logo {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
    width: calc(100% - 50px)
}


.menu-one {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%
}
.toggle{
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-10px);
        -ms-transform: translate(-10px);
            transform: translate(-10px);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle span {
    position: relative;
    width: 36px;
    height: 4px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
} 
}
```

I would recommend you use something like the [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) when you compile your builds for production.

Comment: Hi Andre!
 
Autoprefixer seems like a nice tool, I will use it for sure.

I implemented your changes but the problem remains..